# MySQL Membership Provider for .net 4.5

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, membership-provider, mysql-connector

I'm trying to setup MySQL Membership Provider with Connector 6.7.4.0 and .Net v4.5 but I can't find the Mysql.Web namespace anywhere.

I managed to reference Mysql.Data.dll & Mysql.Data.Entity.dll in the

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.7.4\Assemblies\v4.5"**

I can see that there is a Mysql.Web.dll in the v4.0 folder. I can't seem to find anything from google except for older version of Mysql .Net connector.

Is the membership provider not yet supported in v4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove connector 6.7.4 and install connector 6.6.5

Comment: I'm still hoping there is a light at the end of the tunnel for 6.7.4.  This will be my chosen path if nothing else comes around.